# Can build & make video call with pjsip and ffmpeg

Tags: objective-c, video, ffmpeg, call, pjsip

I try to build PJSIP with ffmpeg with this config:

i Follow those step:

- build need lib and place in thirdparty folder name ffmpeg
- setup link lib & header already.
- run build with "$configure --with-ffmpeg="
- config_site.h add:

> ```
> #define PJMEDIA_HAS_OPENH264_CODEC 1 
> #define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1 
> #define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_FFMPEG 1 
> #define PJMEDIA_HAS_FFMPEG_VID_CODEC 1 
> #define PJMEDIA_HAS_FFMPEG 1 
> #define PJMEDIA_HAS_FFMPEG_CODEC_H264 1 
> #define PJMEDIA_HAS_LIBAVDEVICE 1 
> #define PJMEDIA_HAS_OPENH264_CODEC 1
> ```

I see have to enable PJMEDIA_HAS_OPENH264_CODEC , if not, can build success but when import will receive this error:

```
Undefined symbol: _WelsCreateDecoder
```

cause miss wels package exits in openh264 lib.

The build with success after all with above config but in this:

```
   pj_status_t status = pjsua_vid_enum_codecs(videoCodecInfo, &videoCodecCount);
```

the codec info just show 1 codec is "H264/97" -> is OpenH264 codec, i can't see ffmpeg here.
When im start call like normal, see log openh264 init call/ open camera .

What i need step to using ffmpeg, i can see any docs about it

can you help me?

** this i log call stack:**

```
2023-04-24 10:17:21.522976+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.523 [SIPSample -[SIPSample startEndpointWithEndpointConfiguration:error:]:272] Creating new PSUASIP Endpoint instance.
10:17:21.525         os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.13-dev for POSIX initialized
10:17:21.526         sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
10:17:21.527                  pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0x1050a32c8)
10:17:21.527         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
10:17:21.527        sip_transport.c  .Transport manager created.
10:17:21.527           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED
2023-04-24 10:17:21.528077+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.528         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered

2023-04-24 10:17:21.528204+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.528 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-PSUA-log" registered
2023-04-24 10:17:21.529375+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.529         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered

2023-04-24 10:17:21.529477+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.529 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
2023-04-24 10:17:21.529491+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.529         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered

2023-04-24 10:17:21.529592+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.530 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
2023-04-24 10:17:21.529895+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.529         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered

2023-04-24 10:17:21.530024+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.530 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
2023-04-24 10:17:21.530068+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.530         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered

2023-04-24 10:17:21.530181+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.530         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered

2023-04-24 10:17:21.530217+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.530 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
2023-04-24 10:17:21.530283+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.530 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-PSUA" registered
2023-04-24 10:17:21.530865+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.530         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered

2023-04-24 10:17:21.530970+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.531 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
2023-04-24 10:17:21.677206+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.677        coreaudio_dev.c  .. dev_id 0: iPhone IO device  (in=1, out=1) 8000Hz

2023-04-24 10:17:21.677497+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.677 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]        coreaudio_dev.c  .. dev_id 0: iPhone IO device  (in=1, out=1) 8000Hz
2023-04-24 10:17:21.677588+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.677        coreaudio_dev.c  ..core audio initialized

2023-04-24 10:17:21.677804+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.678 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]        coreaudio_dev.c  ..core audio initialized
2023-04-24 10:17:21.678538+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.678                  pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0x1060684a8)

2023-04-24 10:17:21.678743+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.679 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]                  pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0x1060684a8)
2023-04-24 10:17:21.683380+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.683            pjsua_vid.c  ..Initializing video subsystem..

2023-04-24 10:17:21.683585+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.683 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]            PSUA_vid.c  ..Initializing video subsystem..
2023-04-24 10:17:21.684058+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.684             vid_conf.c  ...Created video conference bridge with 32 ports

2023-04-24 10:17:21.684260+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.684 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]             vid_conf.c  ...Created video conference bridge with 32 ports
2023-04-24 10:17:21.684983+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.684           openh264.cpp  ...OpenH264 codec initialized

2023-04-24 10:17:21.685168+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.685 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]           openh264.cpp  ...OpenH264 codec initialized
2023-04-24 10:17:21.685237+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.685           opengl_dev.c  ...OpenGL device initialized

2023-04-24 10:17:21.685370+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.685 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]           opengl_dev.c  ...OpenGL device initialized
2023-04-24 10:17:21.715616+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.715           darwin_dev.m  ...Darwin video initialized with 5 devices:

2023-04-24 10:17:21.715796+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.716 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]           darwin_dev.m  ...Darwin video initialized with 5 devices:
2023-04-24 10:17:21.715812+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.715           darwin_dev.m  ... 0: [Renderer] iOS - UIView

2023-04-24 10:17:21.715917+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.716 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]           darwin_dev.m  ... 0: [Renderer] iOS - UIView
2023-04-24 10:17:21.715921+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.715           darwin_dev.m  ... 1: [Capturer] AVF - Front Camera

2023-04-24 10:17:21.716006+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.716 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]           darwin_dev.m  ... 1: [Capturer] AVF - Front Camera
2023-04-24 10:17:21.716033+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.716           darwin_dev.m  ... 2: [Capturer] AVF - Back Camera

2023-04-24 10:17:21.716137+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.716           darwin_dev.m  ... 3: [Capturer] AVF - Back Dual Camera

2023-04-24 10:17:21.716152+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.716 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]           darwin_dev.m  ... 2: [Capturer] AVF - Back Camera
2023-04-24 10:17:21.716218+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.716 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]           darwin_dev.m  ... 3: [Capturer] AVF - Back Dual Camera
2023-04-24 10:17:21.716247+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.716           darwin_dev.m  ... 4: [Capturer] AVF - Back Telephoto Camera

2023-04-24 10:17:21.716375+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.716 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]           darwin_dev.m  ... 4: [Capturer] AVF - Back Telephoto Camera
2023-04-24 10:17:21.716409+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.716         colorbar_dev.c  ...Colorbar video src initialized with 2 device(s):

2023-04-24 10:17:21.716673+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.716         colorbar_dev.c  ... 0: Colorbar generator

2023-04-24 10:17:21.716764+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.717 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         colorbar_dev.c  ...Colorbar video src initialized with 2 device(s):
2023-04-24 10:17:21.716918+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.716         colorbar_dev.c  ... 1: Colorbar-active

2023-04-24 10:17:21.716938+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.717 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         colorbar_dev.c  ... 0: Colorbar generator
2023-04-24 10:17:21.717192+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.717 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         colorbar_dev.c  ... 1: Colorbar-active
2023-04-24 10:17:21.717528+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.717         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered

2023-04-24 10:17:21.717645+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642975]  DEBUG   10:17:21.718 [SIPSample void logCallBack(int, const char *, int):1034]         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered
2023-04-24 10:17:21.717710+0700 PSUAKitSample[83000:15642817] 10:17:21.717         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" registered
```